# How to give a default value if the tuple doesn't have second value while doing range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem is that if the tuple doesn't have second element then assume `j` is `99`. However, my code fails because it can't unpack none. How to give the default value of 99 here?

```
test = chain.from_iterable(range(i, j+1) for i, j in [(90, 132), (88, ), (79, 32)])
```

Comment: The easiest way is probably `range(i, j[0] if j else 99) for i, *j in [...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension to create your ranges.

```
#If the second element is not present, consider the stop of the range as 99+1=100
test =[range(t[0], t[1]+1) if len(t) == 2  else range(t[0], 100) for t in [(90, 132), (88, ), (79, 32)] ]
print(test)
#[range(90, 133), range(88, 100), range(79, 33)]
```